# My Fixed SIDEBAR is floating above the footer after height in other div is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a sidebar that floats very well on load & does not overflow above sidebar after scroll till bottom.
On main div i have products & section where products can be filtered. So while using filter the height of the Main Div changes as products reduced when filters are used. Hence after clicking on filter buttons the sidebar overflows above the sidebar cause height is changed or offset is changed.

This is the sidebar floating code.

```
$stick = $('div.sidebar');
$foot = $('#footer');
margin = 80;
offtop = $stick.offset().top - margin;
offbtm = $foot.offset().top - ( margin*3 + $stick.height() );

$(window).scroll(function () {
    scrtop = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scrtop > offtop && $stick.hasClass('natural')) {
    $stick.removeClass('natural').addClass('fixed').css('top', margin);
  }
  if (offtop > scrtop && $stick.hasClass('fixed')) {
    $stick.removeClass('fixed').addClass('natural').css('top', 'auto');
  }
  if (scrtop > offbtm && $stick.hasClass('fixed')) {
    $stick.removeClass('fixed').addClass('bottom').css('top', offbtm+margin);
  }
  if (offbtm > scrtop && $stick.hasClass('bottom')) {
    $stick.removeClass('bottom').addClass('fixed').css('top', margin);
  }
});
</script>
```

Using general filters from here : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_elements.asp

My html is quiet simple. Considerably more like

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-3 sidebar">..</div>
<div class="col-md-9 productsSection">..</div>
</div>

<footer> ...</footer>
```

Comment: show your html as well

Comment: @לבנימלכה updated in question. its quiet simple tho.

Comment: We need to see your HTML/CSS/JS

Answer (score 0):

Since You have it's position : fixed, you can add some margin to the top and bottom to properly position it relative to the browser window. 
For the overflow, try to add this rule 
Overflow-y : hidden 
Overflow-x : auto 
I hope this helps